# abrir um arquivo com php

Tags: php

- algo semelhante o imgur http://imgur.com/ .

Queria procurar o arquivo no meu desktop - *abrir aquela caixa pra procurar o arquivo no disco rígido* - (no meu caso seria abrir um arquivo `.json`), lê-lo e interpreta-lo.

Existe algum material, de preferência php orientado a objetos, para eu acompanhar?

Comment: você quer fazer algo como isso:  `<input type="file" name="arquivo">` ?

Comment: Porque para abrir a caixa de diálogo, começa assim.

Comment: não sabia da existência disso. eu queria abrir o arquivo .json, construir vários elementos dinâmicos com ele no html e depois enviar via ajax pro php gerar uma outra coisa com esse arquivo.

Comment: o nome disso não é "abrir arquivo"... é "upload"

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja algo do tipo:
Arquivo: **mydata.json**

```
 {
  "dataConsulta": "2015-08-02 00:33:20",
  "listaUsuarios": [
    {
      "idUsuario": 1,
      "nome": "Renan",
      "idade": "23",
      "listaEspecialidades": ["PHP", "JS", "MySQL"]
    },
    {
      "idUsuario": 2,
      "nome": "Denali",
      "idade": "23",
      "listaEspecialidades": ["PHP", "JS", "MySQL", ".NET", "SQL Server"]
    }
    ],
    "mensagem": "2 registros encontrados",
    "especialidadesComuns": "PHP, JS, MySQL"
}
```

Arquivo: **uploadJson.php**

```
    //Move o arquivo para um lugar do servidor (A pasta já deve estar criada neste caso)
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],  $dstDir);
    //Pega o conteúdo do arquivo
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($dstDir);
    $objJson = json_decode($fileContent);

    //Agora use o json da forma como quiser
    //Ex.: Lista todos usuários e suas especialidades
    if(sizeof($objJson->listaUsuarios)){
      foreach($objJson->listaUsuarios as $usuario){
         echo "Nome: ".$usuario->nome.";";
         if(sizeof($usuario->listaEspecialidades)){
           echo "Especialidades: ";
           echo implode(", ", $usuario->listaEspecialidades);
         }
         echo "<br>";
      }
    }
    echo $objJson->mensagem." - Consulta realizada em: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($objJson->dataConsulta))."<br>";

    if($objJson->especialidadesComuns){
       echo "Algumas especialidades são comuns entre os usuários: ".$objJson->especialidadesComuns;
    }
  }
?>

<form id="meu-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>Selecione o arquivo: <input type="file" name="arquivo"></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

A funcion json_decode do PHP é poderosíssima, transformando seu texto em um objeto. Caso precise executar métodos com os dados recebidos sugiro que utilize um loader recursivo para povoar as instâncias de suas classes com os objetos recebidos com json.

Espero ter ajudado!